# ASP.NET runtime error: An error occurred loading a configuration file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

```
C:\Users\****\StorageFolder\WEB\MyPage\MyPage.aspx: ASP.NET runtime error: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Invalid file name for file monitoring: 'C:\Users\****\StorageFolder\WEB\web.config'. Common reasons for failure include:
- The filename is not a valid Win32 file name.
- The filename is not an absolute path.
- The filename contains wildcard characters.
- The file specified is a directory
- Access denied. (C:\Users\****\StorageFolder\WEB\web.config)
```

The error occurs on this line of the aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Templates/Default.master" CodeFile="MyPage.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyPage" %>
```

This issue happens when I'm trying to open `MyPage.aspx` and `MyPage.aspx.vb`. This is NOT a website project or visual studio project in any way, just two individual files sitting in a folder.

For the path it is referring to, that `web.config` it references is a folder containing a `web.config` file.

There is no web project or visual studio project relating to these files.  I am not editing this on a web server. VS2012 should have no interest at all in that `web.config` folder as far as I can tell, so why does it?

If I rename that `web.config` folder to something else, the error when opening the page files vanishes, but why is this happening at all?